# Validar si esta el ID buscado por el usuario en la base de datos

Tags: python, base-de-datos, tkinter

Necesito hacer una validación para ver si el ID a buscar esta en la base de datos , si no esta que me tire un mensaje de error o algo así, no se como formularlo , no se me ocurre como poner el `if` para ver si el id esta en la base de datos

```
def ajax(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.obtener_id= self.ingresar_id.get()
    consulta = "SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE id=?"
    result = self.ejecuta_consulta(consulta, (self.obtener_id, ))
    for self.r in result:
        self.get_id = self.r[0]
        self.obtener_nombre= self.r[1]
        self.obtener_precio=self.r[3]
        self.obtener_stock=self.r[2]
    self.nombre_producto.configure(text="Nombre Producto: " + str(self.obtener_nombre)) 
    self.precio_producto.configure(text="Precio Producto: $" + str(self.obtener_precio))


def ejecuta_consulta(self, consulta, parametros=()):
    # Base de datos
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_nombre) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(consulta, parametros)
        conn.commit()
        return result
    raise Exception("No se pudo conectar con la DB")
```

Comment: ¿Qué retorna el método ejecuta_consulta?¿el cursor o la salida de fechall?

Comment: hola como estas ahi te muestro   
 ``` def ejecuta_consulta(self, consulta, parametros=()):
        # Base de datos
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_nombre) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(consulta, parametros)
            conn.commit()
            return result
        raise Exception("No se pudo conectar con la DB")
    # Obtener productos desde la base de datos```

Comment: perdona el formato soy nuevo en el foro no se si se entiende ahi lo que puse

Comment: Hola Maxi, no te preocupes ya irás conociendo ésto, usa siempre el botón editar que hay debajo de la pregunta para agregar información en la propia pregunta, especialmente código, los comentarios se cargan el formato, especialmnte la identación y eso en Python es primordial.

Comment: ya actualice con el ejecuta consulta , quizas ahi entiendes lo que preciso gracias por tu ayuda y atencion

Comment: Perfecto, una duda, ¿la id de existir se espera que sea única?, me refiero, se retornaría una única fila de la tabla o hay varias filas con la misma id. Lo digo porque el enfoque cambia, así como la necesidad o no del ciclo for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu método `ejecuta_consulta` retorna directamente la instancia del cursor, el cual se comporta como un iterador. Dado que asumo que la id es única, la consulta debe retornar una única fila o ninguna.

Puedes usar el método `fetchone`, retornará una única fila de la consulta o `None` si ésta no generó ningún resultado o el iterador está agotado. Puedes valerte de ésto para comprobar si existe o no la id:

```
from tkinter import messagebox


def ajax(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.obtener_id = self.ingresar_id.get()
    consulta = "SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE id=?"
    result = self.ejecuta_consulta(consulta, (self.obtener_id, ))
    self.r = result.fetchone()
    if self.r is not None:
        self.get_id = self.r[0]
        self.obtener_nombre= self.r[1]
        self.obtener_precio=self.r[3]
        self.obtener_stock=self.r[2]

        self.nombre_producto.configure(
            text=f"Nombre Producto: {self.obtener_nombre}"
            ) 
        self.precio_producto.configure(
            text=f"Precio Producto: {self.obtener_precio}$"
            )
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "La id no existe en la base de datos")
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias !!!

Answer (score 2):

Hace poco estuve yo en lo mismo, yo lo solucioné así. De todas formas si quieres que se muestre el resultado en un `ScrolledText` hay que cambiar:

```
self.get_id.set(r[0])
```

por:

```
self.get_id.insert("1.0", r[0])
```

y para borrar el texto:

```
self.get_id.set("")
```

por:

```
self.get_id.delete("1.0", tk.END)
```

Intenta adaptarlo a tu problema.

```
def consultar_id(self)
    obtener_id= self.ingresar_id.get()
    try:
        mi_conexion = self.abrir()
        cursor=mi_conexion.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT *FROM Productos WHERE id = '%s'"%(obtener_id))
        r =  cursor.fetchall()
    finally:
        mi_conexion.close()
    if len(respuesta)>0:
        self.get_id.set(r[0])
        self.obtener_nombre.set(r[1])
        self.obtener_precio.set(r[2])
        self.obtener_stock.set(r[3])
    else:    
        self.get_id.set('')
        self.obtener_nombre.set('')
        self.obtener_precio.set('')
        self.obtener_stock.set('')
        mb.showinfo("Información", "No existe esa id")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 0):

def leer():

```
miConexion=sqlite3.connect("USUARIOS")

miCursor=miConexion.cursor()

miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATOSUSUARIOS WHERE ID="+miID.get())

todosUsuarios=miCursor.fetchall()

for usuario in todosUsuarios:

    #miID.set(usuario[0])
    miNombre.set(usuario[1])
    miPass.set(usuario[2])
    miApellido.set(usuario[3])
    miDireccion.set(usuario[4])
    textoComentario.insert(INSERT, usuario[5])
if len(todosUsuarios)==0:
    messagebox.showwarning("BBDD","Registro no existe")

miCursor.close()
miConexion.close()
```

Tenia ese mismo problema y con esta publicación pude resolver y me quedo así mi código.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Recuerda además que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código.